# Expanding root partition on AWS-ECS Docker contianer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

How do I expand the root partition of all containers of a certain task definition by default? If it expands all containers in an instance or cluster (including the `ECS Agent`), that's still fine.

After reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html, I tried adding 
`#cloud-boothook
cloud-init-per once docker_options echo 'OPTIONS="${OPTIONS} --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker` to the autoscaling group's advanced details, but to no avail.

I also tried (with no success) all of the following (in the same place):

`sed -i '/^EXTRA_DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS/s/"$/ --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage-setup`

`sed -i '/^DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS/s/"$/ --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`

and
`sed -i '/^OPTIONS/s/"$/ --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker`

None of them worked.

I tried updating the ECS-Agent from 1.18 to 1.23. 
These solutions failed on both versions.

`docker info` output:

`Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 3
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-docker--pool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Data Space Used: 4.298GB
 Data Space Total: 106.1GB
 Data Space Available: 101.8GB
 Metadata Space Used: 708.6kB
 Metadata Space Total: 109.1MB
 Metadata Space Available: 108.3MB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.61GB
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.67-66.56.amzn1.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.503GiB
Name: ip-172-30-1-205
ID: YY74:M3ZE:4J6G:W5TW:HI2U:GIWX:3ZJ7:LAM5:K5T3:MHVN:7T3Z:LGQP
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false`

Comment: Please include the output of `docker info`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was close with some of the previous attempts:

I made the mistake of not adding the `#cloud-boothook` line **above** `#! /bin/bash`.

And then I just added the `sed -i '/^OPTIONS/s/"$/ --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker` line after `cloud-init-per once docker_options`

So eventually it looked like:

`#cloud-boothook`

`#! /bin/bash`

`cloud-init-per once docker_options sed -i '/^OPTIONS/s/"$/ --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G"/' /etc/sysconfig/docker`

And that worked.